# Currency Pipe not working?

Tags: angularjs, pipe, nativescript

I'm trying to use the currency pipe to format numbers to Pounds but it just defaults to Dollars. Any help?

Currently, I'm using `currency:'GBP':true`.

I'm using angular and nativescript.

--EDIT--
Sorted it now

Comment: you can post your solution in order for other community members to have access to it

Comment: I just ended up writing my own custom pipe/function

Answer (score -2):

```
 <span>{{amount | currency:'£'}}<span>
```

get symbols from google :)

If you are using ISO 4217 the refer this 
https://github.com/zwacky/isoCurrency

Comment: im using nativescript so i cant really use that